# PHP script with $_GET variables in Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: php, windows, variables, get, scheduled-tasks

How can I pass variables to  a php script in the windows task scheduler?

In the Task Scheduler in "Action" I enter:

**Programms/Scripts:** `C:\php\php.exe`

**Arguments** `C:\scripts\myscript.php?var1=1&var2=2`

**?var1=1&var2=2** is not passed to the php script in the task scheduler. If I call the script with vars in a browser the variables are passed to the script properly.

**EDIT 1**

For better understanding the answers

In the script with GET ich get the data as:

```
$varB = $_GET['B'];
$varC = $_GET['C'];
$varA = $_GET['A'];
```

With the URL I would call it as

**?B=bbb&C=ccc&A=aaa**

How would this example look like if I would do it with argv ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this on the command line, `$_GET`, `$_POST`, etc are all constructed from the web server.

What you *can* do is use proper command-line arguments like:

```
C:\php\php.exe C:\scripts\myscript.php 1 2 "arg with space"
```

And access them with [`$argv`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) like:

```
$var1 = $argv[1]; // 1
$var2 = $argv[2]; // 2
$var3 = $argv[3]; // arg with space
```

And just for clarity's sake, `$argv[0]` is always the name of the script.

**Edit:** For even *more* clarity's sake `$argc` contains the number of arguments passed.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass arguments like below to your PHP script:

`C:\Program Files\PHP\php.exe C:\scripts\script.php arg1 arg2`

Inside the script.php, you can access them using `$argv` as below:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($argv); $i++) {
    echo "$i: {$argv[$i]}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have php-cgi, you can try something like:

```
\xampp\php\php-cgi \scripts\myscript.php -- var1=1&var2=2
```